# Change Value of a tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm having some problem to change text value of a tab at runtime, I tried every answer at stack overflow and any answer solve it.

I want to change the text when I change the tab.
I'm Using for create the tabs this tutorial:

[Material Design Tabs](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

and I capture the event of page Scrolled with this code in my activity:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            TabFragmentFirst frags = (TabFragmentFirst) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Frag1);
            frags.setText("Test");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

And inside of the fragment I have:

```
 public void setText(String text) {

    this.text = text;
    TextView txt = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setText(text);
}
```

and this is what that code returns:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void rafs.jess.TabFragmentFirst.setText(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I don't know what I should do for this code work
I will appreciate if someone can answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
```

`mTabStrip` is container of tabs, which is actually LinearLayout so if you want to change the text of second tab than use `mTabStrip.getChildAt(1);` which will return a view so simply find your textView and set your text, below is generic funtion to change text of your required position.

**Edit**

> Open class `SlidingTabLayout` (can find in library project or if you have added in your project) add below function and call from your
>   fragment/activity where you want to update your tabs.

```
public void setText(String text, int tabPosition) {
        View tabView = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabPosition);
        TextView tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        tabTitleView.setText(text);
    }
```

Comment: this mTabStrip declaration should be where? in my activity or in my fragment ?

Comment: i have update the answer, change in class and update your tabs at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your Tab has 3 children and try this:

```
public static void updateTextTabHost(TabHost tabHost)
    {
        TextView textview0 = (TextView)tabHost.getTabWidget()
                .getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget()
                .getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget()
                .getChildAt(2).findViewById(android.R.id.title);

        textview0.setText("yourTest0");
        textview1.setText("yourTest1");
        textview2.setText("yourTest2");
    }
```